# Gates output waveform

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

[image]

I want to do the waveform of X output. How can I do this?

I am trying to use Tinkercad. There is an oscilloscope so I can see the palm.

[image]

I couldn't get Tinkercad to represent the palm.

It doesn't have to be done using Tinkercad but I thought it would be easier.

Comment: What do you mean by the "palm"? Do you want to simulate the AND gate with the specific clock inputs and graph the output X?

Comment: I want only the waveform of output X. I tried tinkercad so I will see that A and B looks like the same as the first image.The Gate 7408 is the AND. YES, I want to do with those specific clocks inputs the graph output X

Comment: What is a "palm?"  In English, it is the [flat side of the hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hand&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop#Areas) or a [type of tree.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecaceae)  What kind of "palm" are you expecting to see on an oscilloscope?

Comment: @JRE sorry my english are not good. Wrong word the palm :) I want the  waveform of the output X. It doesn't need to be done at the tinkercad. I want in first image to know how to see the output X .How can I create it with A and B that are like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see three oscilloscopes, but I don't see any function generators.

Here is a simple set-up showing how the function generator is connected to some input pins of the 7408:

[image]

Note that the oscilloscope is connected to an output of the 7408 -- in this case pin 9. Ground of the oscilloscope is, of course, connected to the ground of the circuit.

You'll need two function generators -- one for input A and another for input B.

**Update:** I've discovered that the Tinkercad function generators are rather limited, so I'm adding this Falstad simulation to this answer.

[Falstad simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEB2aA2MBOZAOBaFkAmbSQkBSCkAFgGYKBTAWjDACgAlcGmkImlTC9+OHFH7g4-aEiKyQdaMLAJMRAnQQ5smBjARd+A-oON8iYiUX7T5chQmg1suZMLq4iYOuJhFDVSoiYnA0Kjo0cTBw6wlDAHdzU2CTMGQ0KHYkojSM-lD0zMhsngszYT5KrKTq6pCbapKYm0jo2JoYsOCQABNGADMAQwBXABsAF2Yxxl7wCSoYSA4Ac1oumKpOzKJIPyyAB2SBYPwU+cX2I-qKsBsTi8PFKO7n6PVHkoB7KTCJQUw4iQMAgPUwWR+bD+QlymAgTngiKRcFBsBR8w4QA)

The real tricky part is setting up the wave forms for the two inputs. Here are a couple of tips to generate clock signals and setting up the scopes in Falstad:

- For a 5V clock signal set the max. voltage to 2.5V and the DC offset to 2.5V
- set the frequency to around 100 Hz
- to facilitate monitoring digital inputs and outputs, use a "Voltmeter/Scope Probe" found in the "Outputs and Labels" menu
- in the scope settings set the horizontal scale to 2 ms/div
- also for scopes in the "Plots" settings only show voltage

Comment: You'll need two function generators -- one for input A and another for input B.. You mean I should add two generators? and I must put each one generator to input A and B?

Comment: Yes. A and B have different waveforms, so you'll need two generators.

Comment: thanks and could you tell me in the oscilloscope what is the frequent you use?

Comment: It doesn't matter. But you'll want to adjust the time base of the oscilloscope so that it can see the transitions of your signals. If your function generator is set to 1 kHz then you should set the scope's time base to around 1 ms.

Comment: thanks a lot of EnikR

Comment: I added to my answer.